# find rmse etc. of two different lists in r?

Tags: r, list

I have two different data which consist of lists like below. And I want to calculate RMSE between each element of obs and sim.

```
obs<-structure(list(Jan = structure(c(1.37, 0), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2")), Feb = structure(c(0, 0.29), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2")), Mar = structure(c(0, 0.25), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2"))), .Names = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))

sim<-structure(list(Jan = structure(c(6.5, 0.5), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2")), Feb = structure(c(0, 5.5), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2")), Mar = structure(c(0.5, 0), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2"))), .Names = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))
```

Desired output will be like:

```
library(Metrics)    
r1<-rmse(obs$Jan,sim$Jan)
    r2<-rmse(obs$Feb,sim$Feb)
    r3<-rmse(obs$Mar,sim$Mar)
    out<-list(r1,r2,r3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
Map(rmse, obs, sim)
$Jan
[1] 3.644647

$Feb
[1] 3.684026

$Mar
[1] 0.3952847
```

Answer (score 0):

We may also do with `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(Metrics)
map2_dbl(obs, sim, rmse)
```

-ouptut

```
   Jan       Feb       Mar 
3.6446468 3.6840263 0.3952847
```